# Is there an alternative for $expr in older version of MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, operators, version, compatibility

I wrote a MongoDB query to fetch orders that were closed on a given date (matching year and month):

```
const orders = await OrderModel.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: ['$entityId', entityId] },
      { $ne: ['$closingDate', null] },
      { $eq: [{ $year: '$closingDate' }, date.getFullYear()] },
      { $eq: [{ $month: '$closingDate' }, date.getMonth() + 1] },
    ],
  },
}).lean();
```

Turns out my local MongoDB version (`3.6`) is higher than the one on the dev environment (`3.4.14`), and therefore `$expr` isn't supported. Is there an alternative for older version I can use?

*Note: I read the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836885/is-there-an-alternative-for-expr-in-older-versions-of-mongodb) regarding this topic, but I couldn't extract an answer from that as it covers a different use case.*

Comment: Have you tried avoiding `$expr`? Like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WVN0lZWRhlL)

Comment: @J.F. Yes, avoiding it is what I'm trying to do! I just don't know for this specific use case - using the $month and $year operators. Does a standard .find() query support them?

Comment: Hmm that's true, you are using `$year` and `$month`. So maybe you can use `aggregate` with `$match` instead of `find`.

Comment: I changed the query to look for `closingDate: { $ne: null, $gte: current, $lt: next }` and it appears to be working. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Comment: There is no need for `$expr` - but I refuse to give answer by transcribing from a screenshot.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sorry, I wasn't aware. I fixed it. Also, the issue was resolved by using `$gte` and `$lt` operators. Still, I'd love to see a more closer alternative - like using `aggregate`, for example. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to work with dates/times then I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. Looks like, you want to query the data from the current month. Then you could write it like this:

```
db.OrderModel.find({
  entityId: entityId,
  closingDate: {
    $gte: moment().startOf('month').toDate(), 
    $lte: moment().endOf('month').toDate() 
  }
})
```

You don't need `closingDate: {$ne: null}`, it's redundant.